# Filtering data - React JS (Search bar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a small project to practice, im fetching a list of books into a table and i want to be able to search for books in this table based on title.

Im thinking that i have to use the filter method, however im not sure how and where i should use it.

My data is fetched into a table like this:

```
const [dataFromServer, setDataFromServer] = useState([]);
  const [q, setQ] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    apiFacade.getBooks().then((data) => setDataFromServer(data.all));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid padding">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-3"></div>
        <div className="col-6 text-center">
          <h2 className="text-center mt-5 mb-2">Books</h2>
          <p className="text-muted">Search for a book by title</p>

          <div class="input-group rounded mb-5 mt-2">
            <input
              type="search"
              class="form-control rounded"
              placeholder="Search"
              value={q}
              onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              <FaSistrix />
            </button>

          </div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">Publisher</th>
                <th scope="col">Publish year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {dataFromServer && dataFromServer.length > 0 ? (
                dataFromServer.map((m) => (
                  <tr key={m.isbn}>
                    <td>{m.isbn}</td>
                    <td>{m.title}</td>
                    <td>{m.author}</td>
                    <td>{m.publisher}</td>
                    <td>{m.publishYear}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <Spinner animation="border" />
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="col-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I get the input from my search bar into a the state called Q (bad naming)

But how do i filter through the data? Im a huge beginner to this, if u have an answer please explain how and why, so that i actually can learn something.

Comment: Considering you want to perform the search locally, you need to maintain two arrays. Example- response and filteredResponse. When search is being made you can use a regex with .filter operation. Assign this filter array to your filteredResponse array. When user clears the search input you need to restore the original results. You can do this by copying response array into filteredResponse array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow those steps.

- add a new state for filtered data, and keep the original data intact to fallback to it.
- render the filtered data.
- implement a function to filter data from the source data.

  ```
  const [dataFromServer, setDataFromServer] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    apiFacade.getBooks().then((data) => {
       setDataFromServer(data.all);
       setFilteredData(data.all);
    })
  }, []);

  const filtered = (e) => {
    const filtered =
      dataFromServer &&
      dataFromServer.filter((item) => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.toLowerCase());
      });
    setFilteredData(filtered);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid padding">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-3"></div>
        <div className="col-6 text-center">
          <h2 className="text-center mt-5 mb-2">Books</h2>
          <p className="text-muted">Search for a book by title</p>

          <div class="input-group rounded mb-5 mt-2">
            <input
              type="search"
              className="form-control rounded"
              placeholder="Search"
              value={q}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setQ(e.target.value);
                filtered(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              {/* <FaSistrix /> */}
            </button>
          </div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">Publisher</th>
                <th scope="col">Publish year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {filteredData && filteredData.length > 0
                ? filteredData.map((m) => (
                    <tr key={m.id}>
                      <td>{m.title}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
                : null}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="col-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  ```

[try similar working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-austin-089oc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    apiFacade.getBooks().then((data) => 
     setDataFromServer(data.all)
     setFilteredData(data.all));
  }, []); 
I seem to get issues here, i can load the data, but when i type in the bar it wont load the Filtered Data, when i delete in and search bar is empty again, all data is back

Comment: @ThorChristensen, did you follow all the code snippet. ?, you should pass the filtered Data to the map function in the jsx and not the source data.                                              <tbody>
            {filteredData && filteredData.length > 0
              ? filteredData.map((m) => (
                  <tr key={m.id}>
                    <td>{m.title}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              : null}
          </tbody>

Comment: I did exactly the same as u wrote, however it doesnt show filtered data in the table, it shows the initial data, but nothing when you wanna search.

Comment: @ThorChristensen, can you check the working demo link mentioned above, and see what would be different

Comment: The problem seemed to be that it converts to lower case, but all books starts with uppercase, seems to work fine now atleast - thanks

Comment: @ThorChristensen, you right, the input value should be also converted to lowercase. return item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.toLowerCase());. it's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var [filteredData, setFilterData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
    setFilterData(dataFromServer.filter((item) => {return item.title.includes(q)}));
}, [q])
```

Comment: "item.includes is not a function" is the response to this

Comment: if q is an empty string, it will show all the data as string.includes("") is always true.

Comment: is missing the item.title before includes. item is an object, not a string.

Comment: Yeah @Harney you are right about the includes anda empty strings ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of possibilites. I will try to show you a way to filter.

first I believe it is extremely important that you understand how to use the high other function `filter`. [developer.mozilla - JavaScript filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
// You can create one more state to store filteredData. Then you will use this state to render data
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
const [dataFromServer, setDataFromServer] = useState([]);
  const [q, setQ] = useState("")
  
  // Create a filter function
  const filterDataByTitle = (inputValue) => {
    const newDataArray = dataFromServer.filter((book) => book.title.includes(inputValue))
    return setFilteredData(newDataArray)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    apiFacade.getBooks().then((data) => setDataFromServer(data.all));
  }, []);

  // You can create a useEffect that will call filterDataByTitle when q state changes.
  // You can also call the filter function at onChange of input or at a onClick of a button

  useEffect(() => {
    filterDataByTitle(q);
  }, [q])


  return (
    <div className="container-fluid padding">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-3"></div>
        <div className="col-6 text-center">
          <h2 className="text-center mt-5 mb-2">Books</h2>
          <p className="text-muted">Search for a book by title</p>

          <div class="input-group rounded mb-5 mt-2">
            <input
              type="search"
              class="form-control rounded"
              placeholder="Search"
              value={q}
              onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
              <FaSistrix />
            </button>

          </div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">Publisher</th>
                <th scope="col">Publish year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {// Here you can use the filteredData. 0 is falsy so this conditional is enough :)
               filteredData.length ? (
                filteredData.map((m) => (
                  <tr key={m.isbn}>
                    <td>{m.isbn}</td>
                    <td>{m.title}</td>
                    <td>{m.author}</td>
                    <td>{m.publisher}</td>
                    <td>{m.publishYear}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <Spinner animation="border" />
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="col-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So, I hope that it helps you

Comment: This actually makes sense, however now it only renders my initial data on first load, not when u switch to another page and back

Answer (score 0):

add an "onChangeHandler" function, and set it to the change event to your input

```html
const onChangeHandler = e => {
      const value = e.target.value; 
      setQ(value); 
      dataFromServer.filter((data)=>{
        //   ...
      });
  }
  
  return (
  <input
   type="search"
   className="form-control rounded"
   placeholder="Search"
   value={q}
   onChange={(e) => {onChangeHandler} }
  />
            
);
```